# Drivers for HP ScanJet 2400 on Linux

Tags: linux, drivers, scanner

I'm trying to install my scanner "HP ScanJet 2400". I followed the recipe from here: http://www.elcot.in/linuxdrivers_download.php, However, it was not possible at all to detect it, when working in CentOS, Fermi & OSuSE OS.

Doess anyone have any suggestions on how to get this scanner working?

Comment: After connecting the scanner what does your `dmesg` output look like?

Comment: Also did you launch `xsane` afterwards and attempt to scan with the scanner?

Comment: usb 1-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 14

usb 1-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice

ppdev0: registered pardevice

ppdev0: unregistered pardevice

usb 1-1: USB disconnect, address 14

usb 1-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 15

usb 1-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice

Comment: xsane-> no devices available...

Comment: OK so the USB device is seen, it's just getting the drivers working then.

Comment: That's right...libraries /usr/lib/sane/libsane-hp2400.so.* are adequately installed, after "the source" has been transformed by doing                 cp usr/lib/libsane.so usr/lib/libsane-hp2400.so
cp usr/lib/libsane.so.1 usr/lib/libsane-hp2400.so.1
cp usr/lib/libsane.so.1.0.14 usr/lib/libsane-hp2400.so.1.0.14
&/or
cp usr/lib/libsane.la /usr/lib/sane/libsane-hp2400
cp usr/lib/libsane.la /usr/lib/sane/libsane-hp2400.1
cp usr/lib/libsane.la /usr/lib/sane/libsane-hp2400.1.0.18

Comment: Are you running `xsane` as root?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that... such as root & but such as user too.

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening to the drivers...

Comment: @paritto Please update your question with further information. Don't put it in the comments.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about cp. Why are you copying library files around? Please provide details of all steps you took to get the printer working,and in the question, not the comments, please.

Answer (score 0):

My son want to use this scanner under Debian. I searched for support and this question appeared among the first hits so I share my experience here.

Several pages recommend too the link above however SANE supports HP ScanJet 2400 scanner directly [through genesys backend](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-backends.html#S-GENESYS). You can check your installation with `scanimage -L` and scan with `scanimage > test.pnm` from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that ScanJet 2400c backend doesn't work with ScanJet 2400. luckily, I downloaded the driver mentioned in elcot.in before. you can download it from there:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtgSWJHdj-f6iHx8gNo7S7DMN9Y2?e=VzhUdF

by the way I thought adding the following link is better

https://web.archive.org/web/20170729025249/http://www.elcot.in/linuxdrivers_download.php